# killing form and the dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

When going from talking about roots as functionals to talking about roots as vectors in a Euclidian space (root system), does the killing form become the dot product? Are the killing form and dot product equivalent? Humphreys just went straight from the killing form to the dot product. Because the killing of two roots such that one is not a negative of the other is 0, but the dot product is less than zero, if they are simple roots.

Thanks

Comment: Humphrey said that the euclidian space of roots is a Q subspace of the duel space of a cartan sub algebra that gets extended to the reals. What I am asking is how come the Q sub space extended to the reals is not just the original duel space to cartan, what makes it different? I know they have the same values however one is vector arrows and one isn't. In addition one has the killing form. The other has the dot product. And where does the dot product come about from the killing form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The killing form restricted to the Cartan subalgebra is an inner product, thus there is an isometry between the Cartan subalgebra with the killing form and $\mathbb{R}^k$ with the dot product given by choosing an orthonormal (w.r.t. the killing form) basis. This is the equivilance I think you're talking about.

What you're thinking of, is $ < e_\alpha, e_\beta >_K = 0 $ if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not scalar multiples. These $e$s are not the roots but act on the Cartan subalgebra via the roots.

Comment: Ah. Oh I must of mixed up the roots with the cartan elements and root spaces, my bad. So the killing form of two roots is equivalent to the dot product of the roots in R^k?

Comment: In addition, this may be obvious, but the base roots are not an orthonormal basis?

Comment: Yea, there is a choice of basis for $H$ that makes it and the killing form isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^K$ with standard basis the dot product.

Comment: No, they are not, they are not linearly independent and are usually not orthogonal and if the algebra is not simply laced then not not all have the same length.

Comment: Even if it's the basis for the root system, which is linearly independent?

Comment: Sorry I edited it. The basis for the root system of a simple Lie algebra is not orthogonal. The angle between roots is the tool we use to classify all root systems.

Comment: Ah got it, thank you.